# JSON Request validation in WSO2 APIM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I need to validate request and response in `WSO2 APIM`. Can someone please provide the example how to do that. I am using `WSO2` with version 2.6.1

In the below `JSON` I need to validate the email field should have proper email address and it should not be empty.

```
{  
   "User":{  
      "name":"abc",
       "age":"30",
       "email":"abc@xyz.com"

   }
}
```

It should give error or fault message if email is empty or not in proper.
Please provide example I went through many [WSO2 documentation](https://wso2.com/wso2-documentation) but could not able to find it. Thanks

Comment: There is no version as 2.6.1. Are you using 2.6.0? Is this your body of the request to invoke an API?

Comment: Sorry typo error. it should be 2.6.0. Yes the provided json is the body of the request

Answer (score 0):

You can use mediation sequences to achieve this requirement. To validate the request, upload the request for In Flow and for validating the response, upload the sequence for Out Flow.

For official documentation for writing the mediation sequences, follow [1] 
For more information on how to use mediation sequences with api manager follow[2]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Mediating+Messages

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Adding+Mediation+Extensions